# Unable to load scripts from bundle "index.android.bundle"

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native` application on Android device it gives error on red screen:

> unable to load scripts from bundle "index.android.bundle"

Comment: Can you please update the post with your code?

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it solves: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Answer (score 2):

This following steps helped me resolve the problem in following steps.

- If not than (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html . One thing I am not able o understand is that if `react-native init project_name` is creating a project and `react-native run-android` building my project and running on my connected machine then why I need to create a project using android studio ? Even why i do need android studio?

Answer (score 1):

Using npm version 4.3.0 react-native-cli version 2.01 react-native version 0.49.5

In project directory,

- `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file

  index.js --bundle-output
  android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
  android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

The file name has changed from index.android.js to index.js